# Catching Argparse errors and passing it to Discord client

Tags: python, argparse, discord, discord.py

I created a Discord bot that accepts commands, parses them using the argparse module and passes the answer back to the Discord client. However, I am stumped at how to return errors back to the client as well. Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import random
import asyncio
import argparse

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

#Tells you when the bot is ready.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

#The bot listens in on every message. 
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #New command beginning with # to make the bot say "Hello there!" Always remember to begin with # as you have specified the command prefix as # above.
    if message.content.lower().startswith("#greet"):
        userID = message.author.id
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "<@" + userID + ">" + " Hello there!")

    #Another command that accepts parameters.
    if message.content.lower().startswith("#say"):
        args = message.content.split(" ")   #This turns everything in the string after the command "#say" into a string.
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, args[1:])
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args[1:])) #This joins all the strings back without [] and commas.

    #Another, more sophisticated command that accepts parameters parses them.
    if message.content.lower().startswith("#example_function"):
        args = message.content.split(" ")

        #Pass arguments through argparse module.
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example program that accepts input and parses them using argparse...")
        parser.add_argument("var", nargs='?', type=int, default=10, help="This is an example variable...")

        #Catch errors and pass them back to the client.
        try:
            #The variable "dict" is a DICTIONARY. You'll have to access each variable by calling attribute["variable"].
            dict = vars(parser.parse_args(args[1:]))
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, attribute["var"])

        except SystemExit as e:
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, e)

bot.run('...')
```

The above code simply sends the system error (which is 2) to the client whilst printing the error message to the command line - I really want the opposite, for the error message to be sent to the client. How do I do this?

Comment: See the unit test file, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_argparse.py.  It has a `ArgumentParser` subclass that captures the messages.

Comment: How do I use the subclass to catch errors? Could you give a code example?

Comment: argparse docs also talks briefly about customizing the `error`and `exit` methods. You'll have to study that code in `argparse.py`

Answer (score 1):

Your first mistake is using `argparse`.  It's absolutely the wrong tool here.  You should use the [command parsing](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters) and [error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) built into the `discord.ext.commands` extension.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('#')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await bot.send_message(channel, "Missing required argument: {}".format(error.param))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def greet(ctx):
    await bot.say("{} Hello there!".format(ctx.author.mention))

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="say")
async def _say(ctx, *, message):
    await bot.say(message)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def compton_scatter_eq(ctx, a: int, b: int, c):
    await bot.say(str(a + b) + c)

@compton_scatter_eq.error
async def scatter_error(ctx, error):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await bot.send_message(channel, "Could not convert argument to an integer.")
```

Comment: @MonkeyBot2020 Oops, `on_command_error` shuld be decorated with `@bot.event`, not `@bot.error`.  Try it now.

Comment: It's `ctx.send` but thanks for your help dude! Discord.py is now working and my project is up and running!